# What happened to the ReportingService.Render Method()

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, render, reportingservices-2000

Our company started using SQL Server reporting services integrated with sharepoint from the old reporting services with SQL 2000.  The web service that is available is called ReportingService2006 and it has lost the .Render method that used to be available in the old ReportingService.  My question is what happened?  How do I render a report now.  Unfortunately the report viewer control is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The render method was moved from ReportingService to the ReportExecutionService